# Local robo test not working when using app crawler but works with firebase test lab

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

Command I am using

```
java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --robo-script-file <path> --apk-file <path> --android-sdk <path>  --app-package-name <package-name>
```

When I run the above command, the app launches and tries every possible action. But in my robo script I have added action to TERMINATE_CRAWL and ALL_ELEMENTS_IGNORED, except for some clicks which happen before these.

Here is my robo-script, it works perfectlly fine on test lab!:

```json
[
{
    "roboscript": {
        "executionMode": {
          "strict": true
        },
        "postscript": {
          "terminate": true
        }
    },
    "actions": [
    {
         "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
         "elementDescriptors": [
           {
             "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/buttonOnBoardingLogin"
           }
         ]
    },
    {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "replacementText": "08929292929",
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/inputPhoneNumber"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "replacementText": "Nayan1993",
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/inputPassword"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/buttonNext"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
      "delayTime": 4000
    },
    {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/bt_order_again"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
      "elementDescriptors": [
        {
          "resourceId": "com.awantunai.app.alpha:id/transaction_btn"
        }
      ]
  },
    {
        "eventType": "ALL_ELEMENTS_IGNORED"
    },
    {
        "eventType": "TERMINATE_CRAWL"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`crawl_launcher.jar` was not publicly released for quite a while, so it does not include the latest Roboscript features like TERMINATE_CRAWL and ALL_ELEMENTS_IGNORED action kinds.